# NSData: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

It may be the basic swift quetion, But i am new to swift or iOS development. I am getting the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

For the function bellow

```
    func Call() -> NSData?
        {        
            let nilObj: NSData? = nil 
            if(false){  
                  // Doing something     
              }
            else
              {         
                 return nilObj!        
              } 
        }
```

I just want to return the nil NSData in else condition but i am getting error. I am sure i am missing something obvious, Can anybody help.

Comment: just return nil. It is Swift convention to name your methods with a lowercase first letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `nilObj` as optional and initialised it with `nil`. Then in your `else` clause you are trying to unwrap that. For fixing the issue you just need to remove that `!`

Change your code to:

```
func Call() -> NSData?
{        
     let nilObj: NSData? = nil 
     if(false)
     {  
        // Doing something     
     }
     else
     {         
         return nilObj       
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, error says it all! You are trying to forceful unwrap an optional. You should use `if let` syntax while unwrapping an optional.

Answer (score 0):

Optionals in swift can be confusing at first but it helps to keep in mind that they are just an enum like:

```
enum Optional<T> {
   case None
   case Some(T)  // swift enums can have data associated to them
}
```

If you are sure your optional has non-*nil* value, that is, it is a `.Some`, you can access this underlying value through the exclamation mark `!` operator.

In short, force-unwrapping `optional!` is saying "Ok, I'm sure this optional contains non-*nil* value. Give it to me."

This is what's called **force-unwrapping**. You're telling the system to access the value corresponding to `.Some(T)` although you're not checking whether your optional is a `.Some` or a `.None`. If you *force-unwrap* with `!` and your optional turns out to be a `.None`, you will get the runtime error you got `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

As a rule of thumb you should always check your optionals before unwrapping them. In few occasions you should assume an optional is non-*nil* and *force-unwrap* it. Even an `IBOutlet` can turn out to be `nil` if you try to access it in `prepareForSegue` for example. XCode automatically makes outlets *implicitly unwrapped* because for most of your view controller's lifecycle they won't be *nil*. But you still have to take care for yourself of these less common edge cases in which they are *nil*.

You can check if an optional has non-*nil* value the standard way with

```
if optional != nil {
    // force-unwrapping after nil check is fine
    optional!.someMethod()
} else {
    // 'optional' is nil
}
```

A more idiomatic way to do it with swift is through **optional binding**.

```
// binds the constant 'value' to your optional if it is non-nil
if let value = optional {
    value.someMethod()
} else {
    // optional is nil
}
```

A third way to check is with **guard statements**. The semantics of *guard statements* is a bit different from the previous ones though. You can also mix *guard statements* and *optional binding*.

```
guard optional != nil else {
    // optional is nil.
    // by the end of this branch you must exit the block that
    // encloses the guard statement, such as with a return or break
    return
}
// if control reaches here you're guaranteed optional is non-nil
```

*Guard statements* are a neat feature in swift because you can focus on the conditions you want, as opposed to what you don't want. It also keeps the code that handles a violated requirement next to the respective requirement. Compared to doing the same thing with an *if statement*, *guards* improve readability by making your intents explicit.

To know more have a look at the basics section of the [swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).