# XCode Fix-it suggests force unwrap a bool?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to write this:

```
cardVC.hideStatusBar = rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden()
```

But XCode 7.0 complained with an error:

`Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

I clicked the suggested fix and it turned into:

`cardVC.hideStatusBar = (rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden())!`

What does wrapping the statement in parenthesis and adding `!` do exactly? I get that this force unwraps it. If `rootNavController != nil`, then there will be a BOOL value there. However, if `rootNavController` is nil, then does my original statement `rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden()` just return 0 (or false) and that's why we can force unwrap it, essentially returning false if nil?

Comment: try with: `cardVC.hideStatusBar = rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden() as! Bool` .

Comment: @Sulthan So the suggested fix could actually crash if `rootNavController` is nil? Because I'm force-unwrapping a nil value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `rootNavController != nil`, then there will be a BOOL value there

Correct.

> If rootNavController is nil, then does my original statement `rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden()` just return 0 (or false)

No. The original statement will return `nil`. That statement can be read as "if `rootNavController` is not `nil`, return `rootNavController.prefersStatusBarHidden()`. Otherwise return `nil`".

As pointed in the comments, the swift way of providing a default value when unwrapping an optional is through the [*nil coalescing operator*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72): `cardVC.hideStatusBar = rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden() ?? false`. This statement does what you imagined, and can be read as "if `rootNavController` is not `nil`, return `rootNavController.prefersStatusBarHidden()`. Otherwise return false".

Force-unwrapping an optional is something different. while `rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden()` returns an optional, `rootNavController!.prefersStatusBarHidden()` always returns a non-nil value (bool in this case). Force-unwrapping an optional with `nil` value will crash your program during runtime.

Similarly, your force-unwrapping statement can be read as "if `rootNavController` is not `nil`, return `rootNavController.prefersStatusBarHidden()`. Otherwise crash".

In my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971668/5257295) I make a brief explanation about optionals and force-unwrapping you may want to take a look at.

Comment: This is a good answer, but may I suggest adding the nil coalescing operator to provide a default value of value.
`cardVC.hideStatusBar = rootNavController?.prefersStatusBarHidden() ?? false`


https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72

Comment: Well pointed. I have updated the answer to include the nil coalescing operator.