# completion handler error in dispatch_async - optional unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I followed one tutorial implementing fetching data with Dribbble API.
I am stuck on the completion handler error.
I confirmed that `shots` have elements correctly as a NSDictionary type.
Is this caused by race condition of concurrent queue?
Thank you in advance.

DribbbleAPI.swift

```
//
//  DribbbleAPI.swift
//  iShots
//
//  Created by Seo Yoochan on 10/15/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 yoochan. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation


class DribbbleAPI {
    let accessToken = "6d23de112fd5859e7d5658e6b41eee5f1e76291e3327882017457352c56e61a9"

    func loadShots(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {
        let url = "https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots?access_token=" + accessToken

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let shotsURL = NSURL(string: url)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsURL!) {
            (data, resposne, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
              print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                do {

                    let shotsData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)


                    var shots = [Shot]()

                    for shot in shotsData as! NSArray {
                        let shot = Shot(data: shot as! NSDictionary)
                        shots.append(shot)

                    }

                    if shots.count > 0 {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0)){

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                                completion(shots) // error here
                            }
                        }
                    }




                } catch {
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()


    }


}
```

Shot.swift

```
//
//  Shot.swift
//  iShots
//
//  Created by Seo Yoochan on 10/15/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 yoochan. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class Shot {
    var id: Int!
    var title: String!
    var description: String!
    var commentCount: Int!
    var likesCount: Int!
    var viewsCount: Int!
    var commentUrl: String!
    var imageUrl: String!
    var imageData: NSData?

    init(data: NSDictionary){
        self.id = data["id"] as! Int
        self.commentCount = data["comments_count"] as! Int
        self.likesCount = data["likes_count"] as! Int
        self.viewsCount = data["views_count"] as! Int
        self.commentUrl = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "comments_url")
        self.title = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "title")
        self.description = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "description")
        let images = data["images"] as! NSDictionary
        self.imageUrl = getStringFromJSON(images, key: "normal")


    }

    func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {

        if let info = data[key] as? String {
           return info
        }

        return ""
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  iShots
//
//  Created by Seo Yoochan on 10/15/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 yoochan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let api = DribbbleAPI()
        api.loadShots(nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Error logs

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: it's because of you try unwrap a variable with nil value

Comment: First step you need to debug this code: replace **EVERY** forced-unwrap optional with safe unwrapping (with `if let` or other techniques).

Comment: I recommend you read the basic documentation on optionals again as luk2302 said. After that, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32971668/5257295) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33131482/5257295) might help you understand the topic a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call  your method via `api.loadShots(nil)` and later in that method your write `completion(shots)`, which will of course not work if `completion` defined as `((AnyObject) -> Void)!` is `nil`.

You might want to change that code to

```
func loadShots(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)?) {
    ...
    if let callback = completion {
        callback(shots)
    }
    ...
}
```

or even a little bit shorter

```
completion?(shots)
```

Alternatively remove the optional all together if you want the coder to always have to provide a callback which would look like the following. Note that passing nil will not be allowed by the compiler in that case.

```
 func loadShots(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)) {
    ...
    completion(shots)
    ...
}
```

What you currently use in your code is an implictly unwrapped optional which basically means it can hold nil from time to time BUT if it needs to get unwrapped it automatically does so, which will oly work if the value is not nil. Using implictly unwrapped optionals results in the developer (you) having to be more careful or something like your crashs happen.

You might want to [read up on optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) again.